# I have a class method "InitalizeClass" that does some house-keeping and then attempts to add itself to collection but I get an error object required

Tags: vba

```vb
Public Sub InitalizeClass(SacarioSymbol As GroupShapes)
    Dim obfrmGetSymbolName As New frmGetSymbolName
    obfrmGetSymbolName.Show      
    SymbolName = obfrmGetSymbolName.GetSymbolName
    gSacarioSymbolLibrary.add.me
End Sub
```

Everything works fine except the line "gSacarioSymbolLibrary.add.me" I get error Object Required.

Any direction would be appreciated.

Comment: `gSacarioSymbolLibrary.add Me` ?

Comment: even after I make this change, I get an error "Runt-time 424 Object Required"

Comment: How/where is `gSacarioSymbolLibrary` declared and assigned?

Comment: Is this sub inside the class module?

Comment: "Public gSacarioSymbolLibrary" is in main() just beneath the "options Explicit," so it is global.

Comment: "Public gSacarioSymbolLibrary" is in main() just beneath the "options Explicit," so it is global. " Dim gSacarioSymbolLibrary As Collection"  is located in a class "SacarioSymbols", plural. Both classes "SacarioSymbols" and "SacarioSymbol" are instantiating correctly.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247497/discussion-between-bigt95nt0110-and-tim-williams).

Comment: Why is it declared twice though?

Comment: The parameter 'SacarioSymbol' is not used.

Comment: I want to make sure you got the point of @TimWilliams comment.  He was not just pointing out `me` vs `Me`.  He was pointing out that you have an extra period:  `...Library.add.me`.  Did you remove that dot?  That would certainly cause your error.

Comment: There's no really enough detail here to be certain what the issue is, but @TimRoberts point is what I was trying to get across.

Comment: Yes i changed library.add.me to library.add Me and got the same error. The statement seemed to be ok, but it doesn't recognize the argument as a valid "object". I inspected the "Me" object and seems to be fine.